# Is there a generator of lists of words with a specific category of meaning?

Tags: language

I am looking for an online generator of words by categories. What I mean. E. g. I would like to have a list of all numbers, trees, parts of the human body, means of transport, etc. Or at least the specified number of them, e.g. list of 100 numbers, 20 colors, 20 parts of the human body, etc. It would be best to separate them by a comma.

When I search this in Google, I am getting generators of random words, or generators of nouns starting on whatever letter I want. This is not what I am looking for. There are also websites, which group these words, but the words are selected by other text, which would need to be filtered out. For numbers, I was trying to get the list of them via Google Sheets, but I am unable to create a comma-separated list out of them and when trying to generate words from these numerics, Google Translate doesn't do the right job - spelling is incorrect. I was also poking around Wikipedia and other similar projects like Wikidata wondering if this information could be determined. This could be done, but partly as these projects might not include some word categories (e.g. looking to Wikipedia's category Colors, switching to German, you may have some list, but yet there might be pages of names, which don't relate or page names, which include also more (like "one (number)". I am also wondering whether AI may be useful, but GPT is actually down and I am not so familiar with programming. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think what you want is a “Wortfeld”. Search for “Wortfeld Verkehr” to get words related to traffic and vacation for example, or “Wortfeld Körperteile” for words for body parts.

Comment: Hi Juandev! Welcome to german.SE! I fail to understand how this is a question about the german language. Could you make your question explain how this is specific to German?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Well, the only relation is, that the list of words has to be in German. If you think this question doesn't fit here, which stack do you think it does? I am not a programmer to ask in Stack Overflow, I am looking for a user-friendly solution, which could be used in whatever language, but this time as studying German, I am looking for the German one. So we don't have to talk about the software, but we can talk about a study or linguistic resources. Do you think it still doesn't fit?

Comment: In the pre-online age, a physical copy of the book *Roget's Thesaurus* (non-dictionary format version) would provide exactly what you want. A visual dictionary would work almost as well. But either one would take a long time to transcribe. Now we can get wrong or incomplete answers almost instantaneously.  That's progress.

Comment: If you don't get anything useful here, you might try [German Language Stack Exchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @RayButterworth Yes, at the moment I stumble upon such printed bugs. Surprisingly they don't provide them in PDF but printed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the way you asked the question I don't see the connection to the german language. You may want to rephrase your question and become more specific.

> I am getting generators of random words, or generators of nouns starting on whatever letter I want.

The problem with your request is, that grammatical attributes (like "noun") can be determined mechanically. E.g. in a sentence like:

> The <> is in the <>.

every possible word to be filled in instead of the placeholders will be a noun, simply because it is there and not at some other place in the sentence. Contrary to this "categories" in the way you used this term cannot be determined mechanically, because they afford understanding the *meaning* of the word. To find out that "car" is part of the category "vehicles" you need to understand what a "car" actually is.

What computers (not taking AI into account) do right now is to manipulate word lists according to grammatical rules. The first program to do this was "ELIZA" (by Joseph Weizenbaum) and that was done in the seventies. Modern speech recognition is basically a more refined version of that.

> but I am unable to create a comma-separated list out of them

It depends on how the original data look like (again: here off-topic), but i suggest to look into tools like `sed` or `awk` to (re-)format lists. Once you get sample data you could ask how to create comma-separated lists from it over at the UNIX-part of stackexchange.

Comment: Yes, I understand that by using the casual way you can't get specific groups of words. But since we have AI, I thought bots like GPT understands the text and might be able to retrieve words from their memory. At least I have tried GPT3 Da Vinci via openGPT and it was able to list a certain amount of words (e.g. colors) in English and then translate them to German. The question here is whether this method could be used on a larger scale (e.g. training its own clone of GPT).

Comment: But the second way might be, that a certain publisher already prepared such lists manually. But unfortunately, as Ray mentioned above, I am finding some, but they are only printed. That's why I was wondering, wether it would be possible to mine it in the Wiki area, where they are already grouped somehow.